# Sound lost in Chrome (and only Chrome)

Tags: sound, google-chrome, hdmi

I suddenly lost sound in Ubuntu Chrome (no more YouTube, or Spotify, or SoundCloud sound or any other in Chrome). All other apps such as Firefox or VLC work fine.

There are a bunch of nice tips at [this askubuntu entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369064/no-sound-in-html5-and-google-chrome-after-update-to-13-10), but none of them work, and I did not lost sound after an update, so it does not seem related to the ubuntu or chrome, or flash version.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

If you think you might have lost the sound in Chrome after plugging and unplugging an external HDMI monitor, try this:

- Plug in your HDMI monitor again
- In the Ubuntu Sound Settings, make sure that the selected device for sound output is the integrated one, and not the HDMI one
- Try sound in Chrome again
- If it works, unplug your monitor and your Chrome sound should be permanently back

Comment: I've had the problem mentioned in both Firefox and Chrome, and this solved it for me.