# No sound in Chrome browser on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: sound, firefox, google-chrome, alsa, netflix

There are various suggestions for how to fix this but they mostly involve installing or restarting pavu or alsa.
The problem is sound works fine in Firefox and all my programmes except Google Chrome. If I want to watch Netflix on Linux I have no choice but to use Chrome but without sound I must read the subtitles which is not great.
Can someone suggest a way to edit the sound settings for HTML5 playback in Chrome?
Remember, sound works on my computer for everything except Chrome (yes I checked the volume settings).
Thanks

Comment: If you have just upgraded [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/369064/no-sound-in-html5-and-google-chrome-after-update-to-13-10) might help. You can use Firefox (or other browsers) [using PipeLight](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/pipelight-use-silverlight-in-your-linux.html), or use ['Netflix Desktop](http://askubuntu.com/a/219068/178596).

Comment: The following link has the exact answer. The answer still applys to ubuntu 15.04. [fix for no sound in chrome](http://askubuntu.com/questions/369064/no-sound-in-html5-and-google-chrome-after-update-to-13-10)

Comment: still have this problem in Version 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit)

Comment: Try to install "PulseAudio Volume Control ". You will find a lot of settings for sound's control there.